# Querying an Associations::CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a an

```
Associations::CollectionProxy
 [#ModelName id: 1, name: my_model, #ModelName id: 2, name: my_model2]
```

Would the following make a db request?

```
my_association_collection.find_by(id: 2)
```

Or would it reference the existing result?

Comment: It would result in an error as `.find(id: 2)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: My bad, edited to find_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.find` method uses the same rules as `ActiveRecord::Base.find` which is used to retrieve a database row by ID.

So, `my_association_collection.find_by(id: 2)` or `my_association_collection.find(2)` will always execute a `SELECT` query on the database, not reference the existing result.

See [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-find)